# administrador de django acciones personalizadas

Tags: django, excel, django-admin

Estoy intentando hacer una acción para el Django-admin (intentando porque soy nuevo en esto), pero no logro que aparezca en el desplegable que dice "Eliminar Data seleccionado/s"

mi objetivo es importar la data de un archivo previamente subido con `FileField` a la base de datos para posteriomente mostrarla a los usuarios

```
admin.site.register(Data)


def some_action(self, request, queryset):
    # En principio asi obtengo la data que necesito
    # como hago para que "data ejemplo" sea el objeto que selecciono el admin?
    pe.get_records(file_name="Data Ejemplo.xls")
    # Y creo que asi obtengo la descripcion que sale en el desplegable
    self.short_description = "obtener data"


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['data import']




admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: Hola Anthony, por favor toma nota que el ejemplo debe ser repodroducible, no se trata de pegar cualquier cosa. Revisa esta guía __[mcve]__. Si tienes algún problema o error con el código actual, por favor actualiza tu pregunta con la información faltante.

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación de Django en https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#adding-actions-to-the-modeladmin para hacer una acción (action) en el admin, debes seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. Crear la función que será la acción:

   ```
   def action_function(modeladmin, request, queryset):
       pe.get_records(file_name="Data Ejemplo.xls")
   # Se añade un atributo al objeto de la función
   action_function.short_description = 'Obtener data'
   ```

A diferencia de tu función, estas usando el argumento `self` y además, dentro de la función estas añadiendo un atributo a `self` (`self.short_description...`). Lo cual quiere decir que estas añadiendo ese atributo es al `modeladmin` y no al objeto de la función como tal.

2. Añadir la función al `ModelAdmin`:

   ```
   class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       actions = [action_function]
   ```

Aquí la principal diferencia es que si ves, es una lista que contiene el nombre de la función que creaste y quieres usar como acción, mientras que en tu código, posees un string.

Con esto seria suficiente para que funcionara el tema de la acción y administrador de Django.

Pero tu código podría correr si lo volvieras un método de la clase que estas creando, quedando así:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['action_function']

    def action_function(self, request, queryset):
        pe.get_records(file_name="Data Ejemplo.xls")
    action_function.short_description = 'Obtener data'
```

Eso también funcionaria adecuadamente, cualquier duda pregunta. Espero haberte ayudado